# How do I secure Node Red with a CA certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, node-red

I need to secure my Node Red with a CA signed certificate - not a self-signed certificate.  I'm using a Amazon EC2 with Amazon Linux.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved this myself.

For this to work porpoerly - you need a domain name for your Node red.

I used COMODO to get a SSL

**Obtaining the CERT**

1. ssh into server and proceed to home directory where node red is       installed and **run** these commands:
2. > mkdir sslcerts
3. > cd sslcerts
4. > openssl genrsa -out ./private.key 2048
5. > openssl req -new -sha256 -key ./private.key -out ./{yourdomainname}.csr
6. You'll need to the contents of the above created .csr file during the COMODO SSL procedure
7. Follow COMODOs SSL request procedure
8. Once Certificate is issued, you will be given a Certificates.zip       file. Unzip that into another directory
9. In the unzipped directory, use a text editor or Linux command line to create a ca-bundle file.
10. Combine files in this order (I'm using Linux command 'cat' here):

    > $ cat COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
    >   AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > {yourdomainname}.ca-bundle. You need to copy **both** the ca-bundle file you just created AND the {yourdomainname}.crt file over to sslcerts on your server

**Making the certificate usable by Node Red**

12. cd to the home directory where node red is installed then cd into the (hidden) .node-red directory
13. > nano settings.js
14. At the top of this file, uncomment the line: var fs = require("fs");
15. Find and uncomment https: { key: ... }
16. Change the contents to:

    > https: { ca: fs.readFileSync('sslcerts/{yourdomainname}.ca-bundle'), key: fs.readFileSync('sslcerts/private.key'), cert: fs.readFileSync('sslcerts/{yourdomainname}.crt')
    >           }
17. Save this file (CTRL-O), then exit (CTRL-X)
18. Restart node red and CHECK for any startup errors. If you get errors, you most likely has a misspelling in the 'https: {...'

Answer (score 1):

To add an SSL cert to Node Red, add the **https** key to **settings.js**:

```
...
},
https: {
  key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
},
...
```

If you're asking how to obtain a CA signed certificate, there are many routes you can go. Look at [**Lets Encrypt**](https://letsencrypt.org/) for a free and automated solution.